# Passing state object as argument in corda shell

Tags: corda

I know how to pass argument in corda shell for example corDapp, but i have written a custom flow, where the flow is accepting state object as input. can you help with how to pass object as argument in corda shell?

Comment: if you have json try converting into YAML format online .It may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object is in the form: stateName: {arg1: value, arg2: value}